# CodeIgniter - Database Error while connecting from Localhost

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm fairly new to development and I'm completely new to codeigniter.

I've downloaded a CodeIgniter project from my company's server that I inherited from a previous developer.

I need to add a new page to the site. Since I'm new to CI, I (obviously) don't want to edit the live site but I can't get the site to run locally. I'm trying to run it on a local server either through MAMP or through the PHP server in terminal on a Mac running Yosemite 10.10.5.

I've added the project folder to htdocs in MAMP but when I open http://localhost:8888/index.php/contact the screen is blank. When I try to access the same folder through the terminal using:

```
env DB_USER=XXXX DB_PASSWD=XXXX DB_NAME=XXXX php -S localhost:8080
```

(where 'XXXX' is replaced with our database username and password)

I get the following error:

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: core/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 346

Line 346 of `core/Loader.php` is the `public function database` in the attached image.

**Things I've tried:**

> • I've tried changing the `$config['base_url']` to  `'http://localhost:8888/';` but I still get the same error
>
> • Deleting the hostname, username and password from the `database.php` file, still get the same error

I'm not sure why a local version can't access a database when the live site can with the same login credentials? Any help is much appreciated as I just started this new position, this is one of my first projects for the company and it has me stumped. I still need to figure out how to add a page, but I can't even get the site loaded locally so I can work on it.

**Update**

Here's what my `database.php` file looks like.....it's not setup as an array:

`/* The $active_group variable lets you choose which connection group to
make active. By default there is only one group (the 'default' group).
The $active_record variables lets you determine whether or not to load
the active record class */`

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'database_name'; // contains actual name
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

** **Link to video of me (trying to) explain this issue:** **

Link #1: [CodeIgniter Database Error Issue YouTube](https://youtu.be/5p43JyROUOs)

Thanks for your help!

[core/loader.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxSBP.png)

Comment: With Codeigniter I always run a duplicate copy on local host, then make any changes I need to, to the live site from that

Comment: thanks, I am trying to run in local host and getting database error as shown in video at link above

Comment: So I figured this out, thanks very much for all the help! I had (apparently) installed the mysql database in a different location and MAMP couldn't reference it. I realized this because the database I had imported was not showing up in MAMP > PHPMyAdmin. I had followed a Codeigniter tutorial which imported the DB from the terminal - then ran the internal PHP sever from the terminal `php -S localhost:8080`. This is what was causing the database error - there was NO DATABASE! MAMP couldn't see the DB that was uploaded to the terminal folder location.

Comment: The login configuration submitted by @Ankit for the database file in Ci `application > config > database.php` worked. The password needs to be set to `root`. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: Additionally, when I tried to upload the DB into phpmyadmin it was too large, so I had to download it in two separate files from my server. Compressing both files into a zip file before uploading helped also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running it MAMP ( Mac version) Your mysql default password is  "root"

So database config file will look like

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'root';
$db['default']['database'] = 'database_name'; // contains actual name
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Updated `$db['default']['password'] = 'root';`

Comment: thanks Ankit, I tried this but no luck, I still get the error: A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346

Comment: please disregard the reference to the database file. I had made a backup and placed it in my project folder.

Answer (score 2):

The config file is located at `application/config/database.php`

```
$db['default'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',  // pass this
        'username' => 'root',  // pass this
        'password' => '',  // pass this
        'database' => 'database_name',  // pass this
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => TRUE,
        'db_debug' => TRUE,
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array()
);
```

Just pass the parameters in which I have mention `// pass this` and try again.

Comment: thanks, I've changed to these settings and still get the same error. I've downloaded the website database to my local computer and created a DB in MySQl with the same name, imported the .sql file into MySQL through terminal, so CodeIgniter should be trying to access that specific database. It's really frustrating, I can see the favicon for the site so I know it's loading some of the files.....

Comment: I added links to the OP to videos to hopefully explain / illustrate better what I'm working with and the error I'm getting. I have the database file inside the project folder......?

Comment: please ignore the reference to the database file. I had made a backup and placed it in my project folder.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that root has login permission in localhost. Some MySQL instances are very strict on these things.

Comment: thanks Matias, here's what I get when I enter SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION